# Triple join in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a pretty simple sqlite basketball player / assist model:

- players table with id, name and team_id
- assist table with id, player_id and to_id 
  where the player_id refers to the assisting player and the to_id field indicates the recipient of the assist.

Now, I am pretty bad at bare sql. I am able to retrieve all of the assists with

```
SELECT players.name, teams.name, assists.to_id
FROM players
JOIN teams 
on players.team_id = teams.id
JOIN assists
on assists.player_id = players.id
```

and it gives me the name of the assisting player, the name of the team and the id of the recipient (like: Kobe Bryant, LA Laker, 342). What do I have to add to have the name of the recipient instead of the bare id?  It comes from the same players table.

Comment: Hint:  You need another join to `players`.  And table aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT p.name, t.name, a.to_id, p2.name
FROM players p
JOIN teams t on p.team_id = t.id
JOIN assists a on a.player_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN players p2 on a.to_id = p2.id
```

Comment: That's it. I understand your logo.